# How to find a value in a sorted vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I have searched for a solution to my problem, but did not find an answer. The following code is only for learning purposes. I want to erase all elements with value 3 in this vector:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4};
```

I tried to solve it like this:

//only an excerpt from the code

```
iterator erase(T const& elem) {
    return v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), elem), v.end());
}
```

But in my test case, I expect to have the iterator to point to value 4, but in my code it points to value 3. It only removes the first 3 from my vector.

How can I remove both values "3", so that the iterator returned points to 4?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `std::remove` will work, it doesn't take advantage of the fact that the container is sorted. To do that, you need to find the range that contains all of the target values. Like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void remove(std::vector<int>& vec, int value) {
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    auto ub = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    vec.erase(lb, ub);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code works as expected:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4};

auto it = erase(3)
assert(v == std::vector<int>({1,1,2,2,2,4,4});
assert(*it == 4);
```

The returned iterator points past the last element that was removed.

You were simply mis-interpreting the return value of `vector::erase`.

Answer (score 0):

You did everything correct. 
Note that the returned pointer is simply pointing to the new 'end', so you're viewing deallocated memory.

if you simply look at the vector v you will notice that all the '3's were indeed deleted.